# Использование генерика, с возможностью создания словаря Dictionary<Type, <Some, ???>> в другом классе

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Не знаю как правильно сформулировать вопрос, поэтому не получается загуглить.

Есть такой класс

```
public class Some<T>
    //where T : class
{

    public T[] Variable;

}
```

И есть другой, который содержит словарь:

```
class Another
{

    public IDictionary<Type, Some<???>> Somes;

}
```

Вместо `???` нужны разные типы.
Можно было бы создать абстрактный класс для `???` (или интерфейс), записать его туда и в определение `where T : IThird`. Но мне нужно, чтобы была возможность создать `Some<float>`.
Какое есть решение?

**UPDATE** можно и без ограничения `where` (т.к. `float` не подойдет), но основной вопрос остается открытым.
Изменил код.

**P.S.**
Я не могу сделать `class Another<T>` - т.к. в словаре могут рядом размещаться и `Some<int>` и `Some<float>`.

Comment: то есть в один словарь, значения и `Some<float>` и `Some<MyClass>`? Кстати, float не подходит под ограничение `where T : class`

Comment: ну так не указывайте ограничение.

Comment: Поменял код, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Генерики в C# требуют явного задания типа при использовании, причем подстановка конкретного типа превращает генерик в уникальный тип. `Some<int>` и `Some<float>` - это два разных типа. Объявить переменную типа "любой Some" нельзя просто потому, что такого типа нет.

Если ваш код ожидает какого-то общего поведения от всех `Some`, не привязанного к конкретному типу T - вам стоит вынести это поведение в класс-родитель Some, или в какой-то не-генерик интерфейс, который будет реализован в `Some<T>`. И работать с интерфейсом, а не с "любым `Some`"

Answer (score 1):

Как вы знаете, есть ссылочные типы и value type. Ваше ограничение в классе Some говорит о том, что вы будете подставлять вместо Т ссылочный тип. Float - это value-type. Вам нужно либо изменить условие с where: class на where : struct что бы подставлять туда value type. А в чем задача состоит, вы можете описать конкретнее ?

Comment: Я закомментировал ограничение. Не помню точно уже полет мыслей, как оно появилось. Но главный вопрос даже не в этом (нужно будет поменять вопрос). У меня есть объекты классов `Some`, которые включают массивы `T`. Сами работают с этими массивами, классу `Another` не нужна конкретика, но `Another` содержит словарь с `Some`...

Comment: @A1essandro - техническую часть ваше вопроса я понял, я не понял какую бизнес задачу вы решаете. Все зависит от тех операций, которые вы будете проводить над вашими 'T'. Боюсь что от конкретики вы не уйдете. Даже если ваш код компилируется то он спокойно может свалиться в рантайме если фактический тип не поддерживает данную операцию.

Comment: Я еще не продумал всё до мелочей (вообще это больше учебный для меня проект, я раньше на PHP работал, сейчас на c#). Но планирую, что `Another` будет возвращать по ключу, который `Type`, объект класса наследника от `Some<T>` (пусть будет `ChildSome`). Возвращать должен объекту класса, в котором должно быть напрямую прописано `class Executer<ChildSome>` - т.е. через `ChildSome` `Executer` должен корректно работать с типом `T`. **PS** - я сейчас перечитал, и понял, что возврат `Executer`-у не будет работать как я думал.

Comment: я, простите, вас не совсем понял. ChildSome это потомок  от Some<T>, то есть наследуется от generic типа или это потомок от Т ? И то и другое разное наследование. В любом случае, если у вас есть некий Executer<ChildSome> то ваш ChildSome в любом случае должен поддерживать те операции, которые вы собираетесь с ним делать. И скорее всего вам придется добавить ограничение. Так что от абстракций вам не уйти, скорее всего.

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. есть подписчик на вопрос, добавлю ответ на собственный.

Как я сейчас вышел из ситуации (придется использовать преобразование типов):

```
public class Another
{

    private Dictionary<Type, object> _somes;

    //т.к. по бизнес-логике приложения, в словаре должно быть соответствие Тип => объект этого типа, 
    //то добавляю просто объект, тип для ключа определяется в самом методе
    //но это не обязательно
    public void AddSome<TSome, TInSome>(TSome some)
        where TSome : Some<TInSome>
    {
        Type key = typeof(TSome);
        _somes.Add(key, some);
    }

    public TSome GetSome<TSome , TInSome>() 
        where TSome : Some<TInSome>
    {
        return _layers[typeof(TSome)] as TSome ; //преобразование
    }

    ...................................   

}
```

Тогда не так просто будет напутать с типами при использовании:

```
public abstract class Some<T>
{

    private T[] _cells { get; set; } 

    public T GetInner(int i)
    {
        return _cells [i];
    }

}


class SomeChild : Some<float> {}

................................

_m.AddSome<SomeChild, float>(new SomeChild(_t));
```

Да, тут опять придется прописать `, float>`, но если попробовать подставить другой тип - выдаст ошибку во время компиляции. И большой плюс:

```
_m.GetSome<SomeChild, float>(typeKey)
    .GetInner(i) //здесь компилятор точно знает тип (float)
```

Т.е. получилось избавиться от приведения типов в пользовательском коде, но не удалось (пока что) избавиться от него вообще.